# ARM64: Lost with "sxth" in assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, arm64

I'm lost about the use of "sxth" in ARM64 assembly. For example, what's the purpose of "sxth #2" in the following instruction?

`adds w21, w22, w23, sxth #2`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The register `w23` is sign-extended from 16 bits to 32 bits and then left-shifted by 2 places.  In general, if an extension is followed by an immediate, that immediate is a left-shift amount applied after sign/zero extension.

See ARMv8-A Architecture Reference Manual, section C6.2.7 *ADDS (extended register)*.